# Show only icon on mobile and icon and text on desktop

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using [Bootstrap 4.1](http://getbootstrap.com) and would like to display an icon within a button. Of course that's easy:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/users/auth/facebook">
  <i class="fab fa-facebook strong"></i> Facebook
</a>
```

But on mobile devises with less real estate I only want to display the icon and not the text. That used to be easy with Bootstrap 3 but I can't find a solution for this in the 4.1 documentation. How can/should it be done?

Comment: One of the simplest solution will be: Keep both icon and text in your layout. Using media queries, hide the text for smaller screen sizes. You can keep the text inside a span.

Comment: Try this link, you will know http://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/2byptdoL/1/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [display utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/), just adjust the breakpoint with your preferences.

`d-none d-md-inline` means that **Facebook** is hidden starting from the smallest width until the `md` breakpoint, then from `md` up, the element will have the style of `display:inline`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/users/auth/facebook">
  <i class="fab fa-facebook strong">Icon</i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Facebook</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

The visibility classes changed form Bootstrap 3, and for me at the beginning it was also confusing. Essential classes from [bootstap site](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/):

Screen Size Class:

- Hidden on all    **.d-none**
- Hidden only on xs **.d-none .d-sm-block**
- Hidden only on sm    **.d-sm-none .d-md-block**
- Hidden only on md    **.d-md-none .d-lg-block**
- Hidden only on lg    **.d-lg-none .d-xl-block**
- Hidden only on xl    **.d-xl-none**
- Visible on all   **.d-block**
- Visible only on xs   **.d-block .d-sm-none**
- Visible only on sm   **.d-none .d-sm-block .d-md-none**
- Visible only on md   **.d-none .d-md-block .d-lg-none**
- Visible only on lg   **.d-none .d-lg-block .d-xl-none**
- Visible only on xl   **.d-none .d-xl-block**

Answer (score 1):

You can use a media query to do that

```
.fab {
  display: inline;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .fab {
     display: none;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, keep the Facebook text in an inline element like span, and use media queries to not display the span content in small screens.

@media (min-width:320px)  { /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */ }

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {

  a>span{
     display: none;
   }
}
```